# how to combine multiple select statements and input into one table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a table that has completion dates (DT_SolutionStatus_HW).  i want to make a chart that shows cumulative completions over time, which means i need to create a table that holds a count by month of each completion.  I cant figure out how to get each select statement to show up as  its own column (i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar etc.)  This is the start of my sql code as i have not been able to come up with a way to do it.

**MS SQL SERVER**

```sql
Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as [Jan]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'1/1/21' and '1/31/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as [Feb]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'2/1/21' and '2/28/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as [Mar]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'3/1/21' and '3/31/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as [Apr]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'4/1/21' and '4/30/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as [May]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'5/1/21' and '5/31/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as[Jun]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'6/1/21' and '6/30/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit)as[Jul] From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'7/1/21' and '7/31/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as[Aug]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'8/1/21' and '8/31/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) as[Sep]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'9/1/21' and '9/30/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) [Oct]  From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'10/1/21' and '10/31/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) [Nov] From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'11/1/21' and '11/30/21'

Select Distinct count (StarterKit) [Dec] From DT_SolutionStatus_HW where ARBApprove Between'12/1/21' and '12/31/21'
```

Comment: What does `distinct count...` do, I don't think it does what you think

Answer (score 0):

Id echo Charlieface's comments above (i dont have enough reputation to add as a comment).. also, what happens when you go over multiple years?

A better design would be to create a single query display the results each on seperate rows.  This would then allow you to do better aggregation over time frames, rather than having to add columns together.

```
SELECT FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ARBApprove), MONTH(ARBApprove), 01), 'MMM'),
       COUNT(StarterKit) as StarterKit_Volume
FROM DT_SolutionStatus_HW
GROUP BY FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(ARBApprove), MONTH(ARBApprove), 01), 'MMM')
```

An example of how the data should be stored:

```
JAN-21 | 5
FEB-21 | 10
....
```

Displaying this as separate columns would then be a display task, rather than a code task. If you really must do this in code, then you would then need to pivot the results.

```
SELECT [JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC]
FROM  
(SELECT FORMAT(DateFromParts(Year(ARBApprove), Month(ARBApprove), 01),'MMM'), COUNT(StarterKit) AS StarterKit_Volume
FROM DT_SolutionStatus_HW
GROUP BY  FORMAT(DateFromParts(Year(ARBApprove), Month(ARBApprove), 01),'MMM')) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
SUM(StarterKit_Volume)  
FOR Month IN ([JAN],[FEB],[MAR],[APR],[MAY],[JUN],[JUL],[SEP],[OCT],[NOV],[DEC])  
) AS PivotTable;
```